# Can "Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a" be safely ignored?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

For the following pseudo code, nextjs / react would complain `Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>` if the user had previously clicked the Hide Me button and refreshed the page.

```
export NullableLocalStorageAlert = () => {
  const [hide, setHide]  = useState(() => typeof Storage === "undefined" ? false : Boolean(localStorage.getItem("POLICY"));
  const onClickClose = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("POLICY", "1");
    setHide(true);
  };
  if (hide) return null;
  return <><button onClick={onClickClose}>Hide Me</button></>;
};
```

And it would be called

```
export Main = () => {
  return <><h1>Blah</h1><NullableLocalStorageAlert /></>;
}
```

I understand that this error is due to the mismatch between the HTML code rendered on the server and the client. I was able to eliminate the error by "slowing it" with `useEffect`.

**However, does this warning even matter? Can it be safely ignored?**